# Can't add keyword to a short code

Tags: marketing-cloud

MobileConnect/Administration--why can't I add a keyword to a shortcode? The option "Create keyword" is grayed out, and the hover message is "Unavailable." Do I have permissions

Comment: Unavailable means the keyword is already being used for that short code most likely in another BU

Answer (score 1):

When you go to Administration > shortcode you will see the Default Code settings on top. 
This should allow you to create a default HELP and STOP keyword by clicking the 'Create HELP keyword' or 'Create STOP keyword' buttons.

Below you have the Keyword Management section. On the right hand side you have a textbox where you can type the Keyword you want to configure. If it is still available for the code, the 'Create' button becomes available and you get an 'Available' check underneath the textbox. If the keyword is already being used, the 'Create' button will stay greyed out and it wil say 'Unavailable' underneath the textbox

If these stay greyed out when trying a lot of different keywords, or the textbox is greyed out all together, you might have a permission issue and you need to check your users permissions.

If you are Admin and still not able to create a keyword, you will need to contact support to see what's going on.

Comment: Thank you so much..your the best :)